# How to check if template argument is a given value?

Tags: c++

I cant figure out what this line should be:

```
class Mtx : public std::conditional<M==2 && N == 1, _Vec2<T>, 
std::conditional<N == 1 && M == 3, _Vec3<T>, _MtxMN<T, M, N>>>
```

"M==2 && N == 1" is not valid code here I think.

Is what I am trying to do possible? If M=2 and N=1 I want to inherit from _Vec2, If M=3 and N=1 I want to inherit from _Vec3, otherwise from _MtxMN

This is so I can write code:

```
Vec2u v;
v.x=1;
```

Larger code snippet below:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t M, std::size_t N>
struct _MtxMN {
public:
    std::array<T, M*N> v_;
};

template <typename T> 
struct _Vec2 {
    union {
        struct { T x_, y_; };
        struct { T width_, height_; };
        struct { T cols_, rows_; };
        std::array<T, 2> v_;
    };
};

template <typename T>
struct _Vec3 {
    union {
        struct { T x_, y_, z_; };
        struct { T width_, height_, depth_; };
        std::array<T, 3> v_;
    };
};

// M rows N columns
template <typename T, std::size_t M, std::size_t N>
class Mtx : public std::conditional<constexpr(M==2 && N == 1), _Vec2<T>, std::conditional<N == 1 && M == 3, _Vec3<T>, _MtxMN<T, M, N>>>
{
...
}
```

Comment: does this code compile? I think it should and it should work just fine

Comment: sure it does, until you try to use it, then "v_ / x_/ y_is not a valid member of Vec2". It works fine if I just inherit from _MtxMN without the std::conditional

Comment: @bartop [Try it](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cBoC4lEl2Sx5Kus4) (I fixed a couple of obvious things).

Answer (score 1):

An easily readable implementation (in my eyes) could go with partial template specialization:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t M, std::size_t N>
class Mtx : public _MtxMN<T, M, N>
{};

template <typename T>
class Mtx<T, 2, 1> : public _Vec2<T>
{};

template <typename T>
class Mtx<T, 3, 1> : public _Vec3<T>
{};
```

When the compiler looks for matches of your template instantiation, it will enforce the desired inheritance structure.

```
Mtx<int, 3, 6> mtx1; // instantiation that inherits from _MtxMN
Mtx<int, 2, 1> mtx2; // instantiation that inherits from _Vec2
Mtx<int, 3, 1> mtx3; // instantiation that inherits from _Vec3
```

Comment: Must the class functions of Mtx() be re-written for all specializations?

Comment: There is no function Mtx(), these are partial specializations of the class template `Mtx`. And yes, you need to write down every specialization. You can, however, specify only one dimension and let the other one as is (e.g. specialize for every matrix subclass that have 1 column but leave the number of rows as a parameter).

Comment: @lubgr Nice, very nice. The whole question smells a bit wrong, but never mind.

Answer (score 1):

There are some syntax errors in your `Mtx` declaration. It should be

```
class Mtx : public std::conditional<M==2 && N == 1, _Vec2<T>, typename std::conditional<N == 1 && M == 3, _Vec3<T>, _MtxMN<T, M, N>>::type>::type
```

The underlying type of `std::conditional` needs to be refered with `::type`, and for the second `std::conditional` we need to add a `typename` before it since it's a dependant name.
Also removed the `constexpr()` part, that's not needed and doesn't compile on gcc or clang.